# Python split file into list

Tags: python, list

I'm having trouble with the function below. It seems to split the file fine but then only returns it as one element

Function:

```
def splitRoute():
  route = []
  for line in open("route.txt","r").readlines():
    line = line.replace("\r","")
    line = line.replace("\n","")
    line = string.split(line, '>')
    route.append(line) 
  return route
```

Output:

```
[['B', 'F']]
```

route.txt contents:

```
B>F
```

Is it only returning one element because there is only one line in the file? 
I have another function that splits another file into a 7x7 list that works fine but is that only reaching all seven elements across because it has 7 lines?

Comment: Well, what else were you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you replacing newlines? Just split the string:

```
def splitRoute():
  route = []

  for line in open('route.txt', 'r'):
    route.append(line.strip().split('>')) 

  return route
```

Comment: @Schmooo, it also creates a new copy of the list every time `+` is used. I'd suggest using `extend` instead of `append`; then you don't have to use `sum` at all.

Comment: I just realised this doesn't work if the route.txt is multiline. It takes all the lines in the file and adds it to one line in the list. I need it to split it into a 2d list so 2x3 for a three line file.

Answer (score 1):

`split` creates a list. Then you `append` that list to another (empty) list. So the result is that you get a list inside a list. If you had more lines, you'd get a longer list of lists. Here's a quick breakdown of the code:

```
def splitRoute():
  route = []
```

You create an empty list...

```
  for line in open("route.txt","r").readlines():
    line = line.replace("\r","")
    line = line.replace("\n","")
```

For every line, you replace \r and \n characters with empty strings. Note that you could do this more easily using `line.strip()` (`'apple\n\r'.strip()` -> `'apple'`). Also, you should save the file to a filename so you can close it later. Finally, you don't need to use `readlines` here -- just iterate over the file directly.

```
    line = string.split(line, '>')
```

Now you take the string that `line` refers to, split it into a list, and assign the list to `line`. Now `line` looks like this: `['B', 'F']`.

```
    route.append(line) 
    return route
```

Now you've appended `line` to `route`, and `route` looks like this: `[['B', 'F']]`.

If your goal is to create a single list, use `extend` instead of `append`.

```
def splitRoute():
  route = []
  f = open('route.txt', 'r')
  for line in f:
    route.extend(line.strip().split('>'))
  f.close()
  return route
```

Or, using `with`, and adopting a more readable indentation level:

```
def splitRoute():
    route = []
    with open('route.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            route.extend(line.strip().split('>'))
    return route
```

Output for a file with two lines (`'B>F\nF>X\n'`):

```
>>> splitRoute()
['B', 'F', 'F', 'X']
```

Comment: Do I need the list within a list to make it a 2D array or is there a way that this can be done with just one list?

Comment: If you want a 2D array, use `append` instead of `extend`. The most straightforward way to create a 2D array in Python is indeed to create a list of lists. You could also use tuples to index a dict; `d = {}; d[0, 0] = 1; d[0, 1] = 0; d[1, 0] = 1; d[1, 1] = 0` and so on. But this is somewhat slower than a list of lists in most cases.