# In Python, how do you create a list from a file?

Tags: python, list, file

I'm trying to create a list in which each line of a file is its own list of the words in that line. So for example, if the file read:

```
apples oranges bananas

kale spinach

carrots tomatoes celery broccoli
```

Then I'd like the list to read:

```
l = [[["apples"], ["oranges"], ["bananas"]], [["kale"], ["spinach"]], [["carrots"], ["tomatoes"], ["celery"], ["broccoli"]]]
```

What's the best way to do this? readlines?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352697/python-split-file-into-list) for something similar.

Comment: And may I ask why you want each item to be its own single-element `list`?

Answer (score 2):

You may do like this..

```
with open(file) as f:
    print [[[j] for j in i.split()] for i in f if i]
```

Example:

```
>>> s = '''apples oranges bananas

kale spinach

carrots tomatoes celery broccoli'''.splitlines()
>>> [[[j] for j in i.split()] for i in s if i]
[[['apples'], ['oranges'], ['bananas']], [['kale'], ['spinach']], [['carrots'], ['tomatoes'], ['celery'], ['broccoli']]]
```

Comment: `if not i.isspace()` perhaps instead of `if i` since `i` will still contain `\n` for empty lines

Comment: but it shows empty list whenever a new line exists. OP don't expect this.

Comment: Other way round. `splitlines` discards the newlines, but reading lines from a file doesn't

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, like this:

```
L = []
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        L.append(line.split())
```

Comment: PEP8 advises not to use `l` as a variable name

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to explain to @AvinashRaj, you'll need to use something like
 `not i.isspace()` to filter out the empty lines (as they still contain a newline character)

```
with open(file) as fin:
    print [[[j] for j in i.split()] for i in fin if not i.isspace()]
```

The `with` block is called a context manager. It closes `fin` once the end of the block is reached.